# Passing parameters to PrimeFaces Star Rating component?

Tags: java, jsf, parameters, primefaces

I'm trying to make use of the [Star Rating](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/rating.jsf) component from PrimeFaces.  However, it does not allow you to pass in parameters.  That makes it impossible for me to do a lookup to get the entity from the database that I'd like to rate.  I've tried something like this, but with no success:

```
<p:rating value="#{myAction.rating}">
   <f:param name="myObjID" value="#{myObj.id}" />
</p:rating>
```

Is there another way that I can pass the parameter into my action class?  Is there something I'm missing that would allow me to get the behavior I want?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I fail to see how that's useful in this particular example. You're referencing the **same** object in both `#{myObj.myRating}` and `#{myObj.id}`. How is it possible that `#{myObj.myRating}` does not know about its own `id`? Try to come up with a better real world example.

Comment: Imagine viewing an item on an eCommerce site.  You'd like to be able to give it a rating.  I don't want to have to create a new Seam conversation for every single item you view, so I'll need to maintain state and pass the item ID as a parameter so I can set the rating accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this...

```
<h:form>
   <p:rating value="#{myAction.rating}" />
   <input type="hidden" name="selectedObj" value="#{myObj.id}" />
</h:form>
```

Then, in my action class, I'm able to get the value for selectedObj by doing this...

```
String selectedObjID = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("selectedObj");
```

Piece of cake!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows:

```
<h:form>
    <p:rating id="rate" value="#{userHomeControllerBean.rating}">
        <f:param name="contentId" value="#{sharedcontent.content.id}" />
        <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{userHomeControllerBean.onrate}" update="rate" />
        <p:ajax event="cancel" listener="#{userHomeControllerBean.oncancel}" update="rate" />
    </p:rating>
</h:form>
```

In my backing bean, I'm able to get the value for `contentId` as follows:

```
Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
int contentId = Integer.parseInt(params.get("contentId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

f:viewParam lets you pass request parameters to bean properties

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="myObjID" value="#{myObj.id}"/>
</f:metdata>
```

id gets set in the MyObj Bean on page load

```
<p:rating rateListener="#{myObj.myRating}" />
```

Since your bean has the id, when the rateListener method is called the id can be used to save the rating to the database

Comment: Is this available in JSF 1.2?  Or only 2.0?  Our application is making use of 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use f:setPropertyActionListener in your button so that you can send any parameter you want to your action class? or you have to do it inside the p:rating?

or you can do something like

private Rating rating;

//getter -setter

and in your action bean, you can access this value
((UIParameter)rating.getChildren().get(0)).getValue();

if this is the case, you may be doing sth wrong as this shouldn't be the case while you are using JSF.

just my two cents...

Comment: Hmmmm...doesn't seem to work for me.  Either that, or I'm not doing it right.  Do you have an example of how you would set it up?  I may not be doing it right.