# JSP parameter names in HttpServletRequest

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jboss, richfaces, servlets

### Background

Using Eclipse Helios, Apache Tomcat, JSPs, and JBoss RichFaces.

Input parameters are coded as follows:

```
<h:inputHidden name="system_REPORT_RESOURCE" value="city" />
<h:inputHidden name="system_REPORT_FILENAME" value="city" />
<h:inputHidden name="report_REPORT_TITLE" value="City Listing" />
... and others ...
```

### Problem

The following code shows the keys' values:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
protected void setInputParameters() {
  HttpServletRequest request = getServletRequest();
  Enumeration<String> keys = request.getParameterNames();

  while( keys.hasMoreElements() ) {
    String key = keys.nextElement();

    for( String value : request.getParameterValues( key ) ) {
      System.out.println( "KEY: " + key + " VALUE: " + value );
    }
  }
}
```

The framework modifies the keys' names:

```
KEY: j_id2:report_city VALUE: ab
KEY: j_id2:system_REPORT_RESOURCE VALUE: city
KEY: j_id2:j_id11 VALUE: Report
KEY: j_id2:report_REPORT_TITLE VALUE: City Listing
KEY: j_id2:report_int_max_longitude VALUE: 
KEY: j_id2:report_int_min_latitude VALUE: 
KEY: javax.faces.ViewState VALUE: j_id28
KEY: j_id2:system_REPORT_FILENAME VALUE: city
KEY: j_id2 VALUE: j_id2
```

### Update

Changing the `<h:form>` tag to include an `id="form"` attribute results in:

```
KEY: form:system_REPORT_FILENAME VALUE: city
KEY: form VALUE: form
KEY: form:report_city VALUE: ab
KEY: form:report_int_max_longitude VALUE: 
KEY: form:report_REPORT_TITLE VALUE: Canadian City List
KEY: form:system_REPORT_RESOURCE VALUE: city
KEY: form:report_int_min_latitude VALUE: 
KEY: form:j_id10 VALUE: Report
KEY: javax.faces.ViewState VALUE: j_id1
```

This is better, but still not ideal.

### Update 2

The code needs to parse input form parameter names generically. So far, the following code works to remove the prefix (but it feels hackish):

```
  /**
   * Appends the list of HTTP request parameters to the internal parameter
   * map of user input values. Some frameworks prepend the name of the HTML
   * FORM before the name of the input. This method detects the colon and
   * removes the FORM NAME, if present. This means that input parameter
   * names assigned by developers should not contain a colon in the name.
   * (Technically, it is possible, but to avoid potential confusion it
   * should be avoided.)
   */
  protected void setInputParameters() {
    HttpServletRequest request = getServletRequest();
    Iterator<String> keys = getExternalContext().getRequestParameterNames();
    Parameters p = getParameters();

    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
      String key = keys.next();

      for( String value : request.getParameterValues( key ) ) {
        int i = key.indexOf( ':' );

        if( i >= 0 ) {
          key = key.substring( i + 1 );
        }

        p.put( key, value );
      }
    }
  }
```

### Question

What API call returns the parameter names without the `j_id2` prefix?

Removing the `j_id2` prefix (and optional full colon) would likely introduce framework-dependent code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is API to do that, j_id2:XXX is the actual request parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard HTML `<input>` tag.  It works just fine.  In fact, I just posted an answer to my own question where I found using it was the best idea.  See it here:  [Passing parameters to PrimeFaces Star Rating component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821179/passing-parameters-to-primefaces-star-rating-component)

Comment: I don't see what the problem would be in that case.  In my example, your form would simply have a generic hidden input field which is available by iterating through the parameters.

Comment: The framework is for other developers who have their own problems that cannot necessarily be constrained by `<input ...>`. They might, for example, need `<rich:input` values and others.