# property not found + ajax

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use primefaces component called rating inside a datatable.

```
<p:column headerText="Minha Dificuldade" syle="text-align: center; width: 100px">

                <p:rating readonly="false" stars="10"   value="#{cadastroDificuldadeBean.calculaMinhaDificuldade(jogo)}" >

                    <f:param name="jogoId" value="#{jogo.id}" />
                     <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{cadastroDificuldadeBean.onrate}"  /> 
                </p:rating>

</p:column>
```

On page load my column is visible with p:rating calculated (method with parameter). When I click on star to rating an ajax call is submitted (event = "rate") and a throw is shown  Property 'calculaMinhaDificuldade' not found on type 'my class'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821179/passing-parameters-to-primefaces-star-rating-component

Comment: I tried it passing it by input hidden but value is null.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `f:param` on the rating? You should post the full stacktrace here